# How to connect to SQL Server database via adbapi (twisted.enterprise)?

Tags: twisted, pymssql

All the examples I found either mysql or sqlite.

Connect base:

```
connect_base = adbapi.ConnectionPool("mssql", user="test", password="test", host="192.168.0.1", database="test")
```

I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named mssql

Answer (score 2):

Install pymssql

```
pip install pymssql
```

and use:

```
connect_base = adbapi.ConnectionPool("pymssql", user="test", password="test", host="192.168.0.1", database="test")
```